# why the images of camera using Surface view is not same as the image i capture using Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Tags: java, android

I use following Code to capture image. In it I use `Surfaceview`. The captured image is saved in folder  which i create in android Sdcard but when i show these Images in a `GridView` the image orientation is different. If I use camera using `Intent (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` then  output Image is well defined. can any one help me

Here  I have class which extends  Activity  an implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback`

```
public class CameraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

       private static final String TAG = "CameraVeiw";

        private Camera camera;
        boolean previewing = false;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private File file = null;
        private static String mFileName = null;

        private long name;

        final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;
        private int w;
        private int h;

        public   static byte[] data = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera);
       }
```

I use `SurfaceView` to capture Image

```
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceView.getWindowVisibility();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(300, 300); //hard coded

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picbutton);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



    camera.takePicture(new CustomShutter(), null, 
    new CustomPictureCallback());
    }
    });

    }
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
    int height) {

        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();


                previewing = true;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
             camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);        }

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;  
}

class CustomPictureCallback implements Camera.PictureCallback {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

             FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                try {

        String path = "/sdcard/MonsterApp/Photos/" + data+".jpg";
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(path));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");

                camera.startPreview();
                Log.i("Information", "Helllllooooo");   } }




class CustomShutter implements Camera.ShutterCallback {


    public void onShutter() {

    }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(camera != null) {
    camera.release();
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use Intent (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) then it uses default application which never handle orientation of device. The device remains always in landscape only. But in case of surface view when your rotate your device then it handles orientation. So it rotates camera capture also. I think best solution is fix your camera capture activity as landscape and set proper orientation in landscape. I think then your camera will work fine. If you have not understand then i can post some code to you.. But first try.. I am not sure but i think it should work.

Can you try this once

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

write this in your on create then capture using your surface view.

try this to set proper orientation

mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

or

mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

there are four different angles one will definitely work with your code. Try each of them..

Comment: Sorry but When I Use  Android Default Camera and get the Images from Sd card in gridview the Orientation of Image is in well order ... but when i use Surfacview To capture Image than Problem occur (SurfaceView Capture Image In potrait Mode But Show Image in Landscape Mode..)

Comment: yeah i use this code.....  but this code set camera in landscape mode without using this code my camera is in potrait mode....but main prblm is that images shown in landscape mode....

Comment: ok i want to tell you one thing when you use your camera different device having different camera orientations in portrait and landscape mode. So u cannot handle it for every device and still if you want to set your rotation for portrait mode then i am posting some code try it tell me is it front cam or back.

Comment: yeah i try this code in ME Tablet and My Gallaxy Duos ...and in both camera open in potrait mode but in gridview these images are shown in Landscape mode...

Comment: thats what you need to orient camera in 90 and use setDisplayOrientation for that purpose before starting your preview.

Comment: It is not changing angle of image or it is crashing.

Comment: means you have set it after starting your preview

Comment: i use this where surface Created and camera open

Comment: I have just edited can you check you need to set orientation in degrees

Answer (score 0):

There is a metadata with all images captured form android camera. I think you are not saving the EXIF metadata with the image when capturing with surface view. EXIF metadata contain the orientation details of the phone while taking the image. So android system rotates the image according to the orientation details while showing. This details may help you

http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/

Comment: Given link is not available(404 found)